# LUA How to fix Garry's Mod weapon? (attempt to compare nil with number)

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

In the lua I get a error called (attempt to compare nil with number)

It is at this point line 21     if `CurTime() > self.LifeTime` then return false end

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Looks like one of the values in the comparison is `nil`, most likely `self.LifeTime`, so you'll need to figure out why it's `nil` when you expect it to be something else.

Comment: I fixed it I believe

Answer (score 0):

`CurTime() > self.LifeTime` compares two values.

The error tells you that one of them is a number and the other one is nil.
You cannot compare something with nil so Lua doesn't know what to do

print both values to find out which one is `nil` and which one is a number. Then find out why it is `nil` and fix that or avoid to compare them in that case.